# Paypal express payments not completing for contributions

Tags: drupal, contributions, paypal

We are running Drupal 7.50 and CiviCRM 4.7.8.

Contributions and memberships are being processed by Paypal express, users are getting confirmation and receipt numbers but Civi is showing them as Pending (Incomplete Transaction).

Weird thing is that event fees using the same setup is working fine.

How could I debug this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Joe, one of our clients reported a similar issue using 4.7.9 but it was a single contribution so I didn't have enough info to go by to see if it was a systemic issue - could you clarify that the impacted contributions are coming from online contribution pages where (as you state) online event registration payments are showing as completed? What about back office contributions and paid event registration?

Comment: Hi Tamar. Thanks for your response. We have two types of payments setup. 1. Memberships through contribution pages - these aren't getting recorded as paid. Even though the user gets redirected back to our site with a reciept and the paypal reciept number. 2. Paid events through civievent - these are working fine. Both are using the same paypal setup. Let me know any other info that could be helpful. thanks

Comment: I've turned Drupal logging on and done a test contribution. I get the following notice.  Notice: Undefined index: payment_status_id in CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution_Utils::processConfirm() (line 175 of /home/bigpicture/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution/Utils.php). Any help?

Comment: Hi Joe, I have been struggling with this one but I think you actually found the issue - more of our clients have been reporting the same issue - I will provide our developer with what you have found and will let you know what was done to fix. Thank YOU!

Comment: Hi Joe, Stumbled across this on JIRA: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18483 and it loops back to a post made here 3 months ago on stack exchange: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11028/paypal-payments-pending-incomplete-transaction - there are also a bunch of related posts in the right-hand side bar when looking at this post - so, it looks like core is tackling this issue but with little success as of yet - I would suggest following the JIRA ticket to keep yourself updated when the issue is resolved. Hope this helps!

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that the the 4.7.11 release fixed the issue for us. Thanks CIVICRM community!