# Joomla PayPal standard IPN configuration - Pending (Incomplete Transaction)

Tags: civicontribute, joomla, paypal

What should the IPN be for a Joomla site

Joomla 3.6.2
Civicrm 4.7.11

PayPal standard transactgion are sticking as pending.  The  documentation states that the IPN should just be http://www.domain.com/ however this no longer works.

CRM-18483 has been logged about this issue. However it appears to be down to the IPN settings.  What should they be????  Anyone got an example that is working?

[http://*domain*/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/extern/ipn.php](http://_domain_/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/extern/ipn.php)

...doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this thread:

[Paypal payments - Pending (Incomplete Transaction)](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11028/paypal-payments-pending-incomplete-transaction)

Every time we upgrade CiviCRM I have to overwrite ipn.php with a version from 4.4 to get Paypal payments working again.